# How to pass generic type to extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics

I am using Quartz.Net scheduler library in .Net Core.
And it has an extension method. But I want to use it dynamically.
How can I pass generic type of my classes from its string key ?
RUQRAktarim is my generic class. I have another classes like it.
And I don't want to repeat code which is in below. I have my class names as a string in appsettings.
So i want to repeat this code from string class names. [app.UseQuartzJob<"classname">]

Original code like that :

```cs
app.UseQuartzJob<RUQRAktarim>(new List<TriggerBuilder>
{
    TriggerBuilder.Create()
                  .WithIdentity("Trigger" + i.ToString(),jobName)
                  .WithCronSchedule(cronExpression,
                       x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()),
});
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: How about using a loop to register all your types?

Comment: I will do it.But my loop key will be string class name.